# Android Import incorrectly includes min SDK JARs instead of target

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, import, jar

Hopefully I am not missing something obvious.  I have done a good bit of work to isolate this issue.  Say I create a new Android project:

```
Target Platform: Google APIs Android 3.1 (API 12)
Min Platform: Android 2.2 Froyo (API 8)
```

When the project is created, AndroidManifest.xml shows min=8, target=15 (not sure why 15 and not 12 actually, but that's not the issue).  And this looks fine:

```
included JAR: Google APIs [Android 3.1]
project.properties shows target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:12
```

So far, so good.

Now, without even editing the fresh project, I remove that project from the workspace, move it somewhere, and import using **Import->Android->Existing Android Code into Workspace**.
Now:

```
Included JAR: Android 2.2
project.properties shows target=android-8
```

And the project now has errors due to things like the Holo style not being present in 2.2.

I tried Project->Clean, nothing.  I tried **Android->Fix Project Properties**.  No change.

The only fix is to remove the project, delete the project.properties, update the `AndroidManifest.xml` to use `min-sdk` 12, and re-import.  Even, then, I don't get the Google JAR:

```
Included JAR: Android 3.1
project.properties shows target=android-12
```

It seems like the import process incorrectly uses the min SDK value instead of the target when creating the project.  Or is this somehow expected behavior?  What am I missing?

(This scenario may seem a bit contrived, but I am an instructor trying to import student assignments. So this is causing me difficulties!)

Answer (score 1):

Right click the imported project and go to

Properties - Android - Project Build Target

Specify the build target as the target sdk version.

Now it should include the correct jar file.

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps as a quicker workaround, but can you explain the import behavior?  It almost seems like a bug, but I would think it would be more widely reported.  Either my Googling skills are weak, or it's not affecting/bothering anyone else...

Comment: @catapult Sorry. I don't know more details about this.